Create directories manually when install Linux on VMware
I need help to solve this task:
Install Ubuntu inside VMware and perform the following customizations (interactive, manual installation):
Create Four Directories:

swap
/
/home
/opt

How can I create these directories? when I install Ubuntu inside VMware these directories are automatically created, how do I make this manually?
Thank you

Is this some kind of homework problem? Why would you need to do this action manually?

The installer is supposed to do that for you. What are you trying to achieve?

This question is similar to: How to use manual partitioning during installation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

While partitioning select manual disk partitioning and create partitions. For more details use this thread.
